# how to perform ternary operation in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

Am new to `nodejs.`am trying to perform ternary operation in nodejs code
here is the code segment am using

```
 if (filter.serverId != "0") {// filter server details from report
                     filterJson(report, report[items].server,  filter.serverId, function ( filterdData) {
                        report = filterdData;
                      });
                   }else report = report;
```

can i write code like this

```
report = filter.serverId != "0" ? filterJson(report, report[items].server, filter.serverId, function (filterdData) {
  report = filterdData;
}); : report
```

Comment: `report = report` ???

Comment: Why not use an if-statement for that? What is the advantage of ternary operator here? The ternary operation make it less read- and maintainable in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In short, you have no reason to use the ternary operator.** Full explanation and solutions below.

The two code snippets are saying different things. The first one has *two* assignments. It does `report = filterdData` in the anonymous function, if condition is true, otherwise assigns `report` to `report`.

The second code snippet has *three* assignments. It will do `report = filterdData` in the anonymous function is condition is true, and then it assigns the result of `filterJson` to report (I am guessing filterJson returns undefined). If condition was false, it reassigns `report` to `report` again.

### Solutions

So first of all, your "else" does nothing. It just assigns `report` to itself. Get rid of it. Secondly, you are assigning the result `filterJson` to `report`, but that's not how you want to use `filterJson` (I assume).

This will do what you want.

```
if (filter.serverId != "0") {
    filterJson(report, report[items].server,  filter.serverId, function (filterdData) {
        report = filterdData;
    });
}
```

If you just want to get rid of the curly braces, you can do that, but it is considered good style to keep them.

```
if (filter.serverId != "0")
    filterJson(report, report[items].server,  filter.serverId, function (filterdData) {
        report = filterdData;
    });
```

The ternary operator isn't really usable here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ternary operations, but in this particular case it would probably not work. (Apart from the semicolon after the filterJson call, which should be omitted for the ternary to be valid code.)

In this case, the filterJson method seems to set `report = filterdData` in a callback function. We can probably assume that filterJson does not return anything to outer statement, i.e. should you have done `report = filterJson(...)` it would have the same result as `report = undefined`. If the callback function is called synchronously by filterJson, it would be executed before the outer statement, and report would set for a moment, only to be overwritten by the outer statement immediately after.

The effect is something like: `report = filterdData; report = undefined;`